# Error when checking target: expected dense_33 to have 2 dimensions, but got arrays with shape(80, 2, 2)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXmYH.png)Hi guys I have a problem with my CNN model, I have 80 training samples (3D samples), hence my X train shape is (80, 300, 300, 40, 1) and that of y (labels) train is (80, 2, 2) after one hot-encoding since my num_classes is 2. However, I still get error message for my shape even though I make sure I Flatten before Dense. Which part might I get wrong ?

Another thing is that my model seems to be taking 80 samples at one time for training even though I specified the batch size to be 20, where might I do wrong?

Thank you for the assistance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnlGF.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it is fairly hard to answer this question since you haven't provided any of the relevant code. Also please don't paste images. Paste it as text and format it correctly!

Comment: That being said: your model architecture is outputting (batch_size, 2) but your y data are of the form (batch_size, 2, 2). What is it you are trying to model here? What is your y data supposed to be?

Comment: Hi please click on the 1 on my first row for the code, somehow the code is there.

Comment: I just used panda.dummies so that for all the training samples there will be either 1 or 0 for the label. I think since that I have two classes here, it will be (batch_size, 2, 2).

Comment: Another strange thing is that the while I specified my batch_size to be 20, I am not sure why my error message returned my total number of training samples instead. It is supposed to be (20,2,2) but in the error message is (80, 2,2)